# display div if dropdownlist value is selected with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-select

I'm trying to make a Div appear if special "option" is selected in a Drop Down list. No matter what I try I can't make it work. I tried other pages here but nothing seems to make it work.

My C# code

```
protected void ddlSubject_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ddlEmne.SelectedValue == "Lej os")
    {
        divselected.Visible = true;
    }
    if (ddlEmne.SelectedValue == "")
    {
        divselected.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

My DropDownList:

```
<asp:DropDownList CssClass="margtop" ID="ddlEmne"  runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlSubject_SelectedIndexChanged">
                <asp:ListItem Value="Pakke Løsninger">Pakke Løsninger</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Spørgsmål">Spørgsmål</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Lej os">Lej os</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Andet">Andet</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
```

and the div I want to show/hide :

```
<div id="divselected" runat="server" style="visibility: hidden;">
    s
</div>
```

Hope that someone can say that I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to Enable the `AutoPostBack` of the dropdownlist for raising the *OnSelectedIndexChanged*  event on server side.

```
asp:DropDownList CssClass="margtop" ID="ddlEmne" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlSubject_SelectedIndexChanged">
```

and change the markup: visible is the attribute of html elements, so you can directly use it like this.

```
 <div id="divselected" runat="server" visible="false">
    s
 </div>
```

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen look at the edit, it will solve the problem