# My panel fails to show if the user clicks a specific drop down list item

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am attempting to get a `<div>` to appear when a specific `ListItem` is selected.

In my code behind I have:

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{                       
    if (reportedBefore.SelectedItem.Text=="yes") 
    {
        reportedBeforePanel.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        reportedBeforePanel.Visible = false;
    }                   
}
```

I referred to [this article here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21068367/display-div-if-dropdownlist-value-is-selected-with-c-sharp) initially, which stated I needed a few things:

> You need to Enable the AutoPostBack of the dropdownlist for raising the OnSelectedIndexChanged event on server side.

```
AutoPostBack="true"
OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged
```

Admittedly, I did not have an `AutoPostBack` before. After adding it, I am afraid for some reason the requested `div` still does not show.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="reportedBefore" CssClass="larger-drop-2" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <asp:ListItem Text="Select" Value="Select"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="No"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="Yes"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Unsure" Value="Unsure"></asp:ListItem>
 </asp:DropDownList>
   <asp:Panel ID="reportedBeforePanel" runat="server" Visible="false">
            <div id="showDiv">
              <label for="yesDetails">
                 Please provide details
              </label>
      <asp:TextBox ID="yesDetails" CssClass="third-w-form" runat="server"/>
             </div>
  </asp:Panel>
```

Would someone be so kind to help me out here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the following `if`-condition:

```
reportedBefore.SelectedItem.Text=="yes"
```

By this, you are doing a case-sensitive string comparison (this is the default in .NET), but the values in your dropdownlist are written in a different way (**"Yes"** vs. **"yes"**).

In order to fix this, either perform a case-insensitive string comparison

```
string.Compare(reportedBefore.SelectedItem.Text, "yes", true) == 0
```

or change the casing in the `if`-statement.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for this. How silly of me, I should have known. I have changed the if statement to "Yes", but I am still having no luck. I have made this, to show you my CodeFile https://jsfiddle.net/buaxvz8c/1/ - thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint and check whether the postback really occurs when the selected item is changed?

Comment: That's just it Markus, I don't think the postback occours. Usually it renders slightly but I get nothing. Most odd.

Comment: Is your dropdownlist surrounded by an `UpdatePanel`?

Comment: No :-( How can I do that?

Comment: You don't need to add an `UpdatePanel` - if you don't have one up to now, don't add it before the problem is solved to make things not more complex than they were. Can you set a breakpoint in `DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged`? If it is hit, the postback occurs.

Answer (score 1):

C# is case sensitive, so it's `"Yes"` not `"yes"`:

```
reportedBeforePanel.Visible = reportedBefore.SelectedItem.Text == "Yes";
```

Alternatievely you can use this:

```
reportedBeforePanel.Visible = reportedBefore.SelectedItem.Text.Equals("yes", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

Comment: Hi Tim! I fear I may be doing something very wrong. I have changed my if statement, albeit taking into consideration your notes, but for some reason I am still having no luck. Can you confirm my CodeFile is OK? http://jsfiddle.net/buaxvz8c/1/

Comment: @davvv: it should work, at least it is ensured that the panel will be rendered as a div in client side html. But of course you could have CSS or javascript which makes `showDiv` invisible. But you havent shown.

Comment: Thanks Tim. I have no CSS/JS which hides it. `showDiv` isn't infact declared at all in the CSS?

Comment: @davvv: it doesn't need to be declared explcitely there, css works with inheritance and classes or types and many other ways.

Comment: I can't be 100% sure that the postback occours Tim. Usually it refreshes almost slightly, but I don't get anything for some reason. Any ideas? Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @davvv: are you using an `UpdatePanel`?